# How to query posts stored between MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have user information, user-posted content and friends all in separate tables.

user:

```
id    user          email
1     userA         myemail@testa.com
2     userB         myemail@testb.com
3     userC         myemail@testc.com
```

content

```
id    userid        date                    text
1     1             2015-09-01 00:00:00     content here
2     2             2015-09-02 00:00:00     more content here a
3     3             2015-09-03 00:00:00     more content here b
4     4             2015-09-04 00:00:00     more content here c
```

friends

```
id    userid1  userid2
1     1          2
2     2          3
3     2          4
```

How would I query this data to get the content for all friends of a particular user sorted by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select from user_content inner joined on friends, grabbing all content for either user where the user_content record does not belong to the current user but the current user is one of the friends... or just look at the query

**Edit:** forgot to add the limit for just the last 30 posts

```
SELECT
     uc.user_id AS friend_user_id
    ,u.username AS friend_username
    ,u.email AS friend_email
    ,uc.date
    ,uc.text
FROM user_content uc
INNER JOIN friends f ON uc.user_id IN (f.user_id_1,f.user_id_2)
INNER JOIN user u ON uc.user_id = u.id
WHERE uc.user_id != ? AND ? IN (f.user_id_1, f.user_id2)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT u.`username`, u.`email`, c.`text`, c.`date`
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN friends AS f ON f.`user_id_1` = u.`id`
LEFT JOIN user_content AS c ON c.`user_id` = f.`user_id_2`
WHERE u.`username` = 'userA'
ORDER BY c.`date` ASC
LIMIT 0,30
```

This connects the table `friends`, `user` and `user_content` according to your conditions.

Comment: Addition: You could `LEFT JOIN` the user-table again (with different alias) to include the users friends name, by adding: `LEFT JOIN user AS uf ON f.\`user_id_2\` = uf.\`id\`` before `WHERE`, and add `, uf.\`username\` as \`friendname\`` before `FROM`

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely get your goal.

But here is my approach to get all content of friends of some `?` user:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb40e/2

```
SELECT uc.*
FROM user_content uc
INNER JOIN friends f
ON f.user_id_2 = uc.user_id
  AND f.user_id_1 = ?
```

**UPDATE** If you are not sure which field is `uder_id` and which is `friend_id` you can transform it with `OR`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb40e/3

```
SELECT uc.*
FROM user_content uc
INNER JOIN friends f
ON (f.user_id_2 = uc.user_id
  AND f.user_id_1 = ?)
  OR (f.user_id_1 = uc.user_id
  AND f.user_id_2 = ?)
```

Comment: you mean the problem is your data? which is not normalized? so your `friend_id` vs `user_id`  is not properly defined and called `user_id_1` and `user_id_2` ?